# Как сделать несколько кнопок переключателей?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, uwp

Помогите пожалуйста сообразить как сделать несколько кнопок(вроде ToggleButton) Штуки 3 нажимаю одну открывается например ListView, нажимаю другую эта отжимается и включается GridView (причем если несколько раз кликать на одну и туже кнопку, чтобы она не отжималась) [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Изобжение одной из попыток...

Comment: Как вариант можно использовать radio и стилизовать под кнопки.

Comment: Я тоже думал так сделать, но верил, что есть вариант получше...)

Comment: Куда уж лучше. Вы хотите вида ToggleButton, а поведение радиокнопок. Так взять поведение радио и вид ToggleButton - самое оптимальное решение.

Comment: @vitidev Спасибо за помощь) Пойду пробовать и гуглить)

Answer (score 2):

Например, так (основываясь на комментарии @vitidev):

```
<StackPanel>
    <StackPanel.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="RadioButton" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ToggleButton}}"/>
    </StackPanel.Resources>
    <RadioButton>Первый</RadioButton>
    <RadioButton>Второй</RadioButton>
    <RadioButton>Третий</RadioButton>
</StackPanel>
```

---

Если `BasedOn` не поддерживается, можно просто:

```
<StackPanel>
    <RadioButton Style="{StaticResource {x:Type ToggleButton}}">Первый</RadioButton>
    <RadioButton Style="{StaticResource {x:Type ToggleButton}}">Второй</RadioButton>
    <RadioButton Style="{StaticResource {x:Type ToggleButton}}">Третий</RadioButton>
</StackPanel>
```

---

Окей, если и `x:Type` не поддерживается, тогда делаем обходной манёвр.

В `MainWindow` свойство, содержащее нужный стиль, и заполняем его в `Loaded`:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Loaded += (o, args) => ToggleButtonStyle = (Style)FindResource(typeof(ToggleButton));
    }

    public Style ToggleButtonStyle
    {
        get { return (Style)GetValue(ToggleButtonStyleProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ToggleButtonStyleProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ToggleButtonStyleProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ToggleButtonStyle", typeof(Style), typeof(MainWindow));
}
```

Нужный стиль теперь грузим через привязку:

```
<RadioButton Style="{Binding ToggleButtonStyle, ElementName=Main}">Первый</RadioButton>
```

и т. д. Не забудьте дать окну имя `Name="Main"`. Или в UWP, кажется, можно использовать `x:Bind` без имени.

```
<RadioButton Style="{x:Bind ToggleButtonStyle, Mode=OneWay}">Первый</RadioButton>
```

Comment: В универсал он говорит BasedOn не поддерживается( Ну ничего, я уже почти привык ковыряться в шаблоне, и смог его перерисовать под ToggleButton) Правда на счет красиво откидывающейся тени вопрос все еще открыт... Похоже мне придеться нарисовать ее также в шаблоне)

Comment: @Denisok: Обновил ответ, попробуйте так ещё.

Comment: Так говорит x:Type не поддерживается) И если попробовать удалить его + одни фигурные скобочки тоже не получилось... Тогда не удается разрешить ресурс

Comment: Вообще UWP местами какое-то дно... Старые возможности они убрали, а про замену не говорят(либо же я просто не нашел)...

Comment: @Denisok: Ещё один вариант, пробуйте :)

Comment: @Denisok: Стоп, было неправильно, пробуйте теперь.

Comment: @Denisok как это BasedOn не поддерживается. Тут https://msdn.microsoft.com/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/styling-controls упоминается.

Comment: Мне виз студия так написала...(

Comment: Я добавил в вопрос скриншот трудностей вашей новой попытки)

Comment: Я, впринципе, смог сделать задуманное просто перерисовав шаблон, потом еще раз попробую сделать с BasedOn скопировав весь код с MSDN

Comment: @Denisok Не такой BasedOn  нужен. По идее нужно создать пустой стиль для tooglebutton и дать ему имя и уже потом создать стиль для радио и сделать BasedOn на пустой стиль для tooglebutton
как тут показано http://www.it1me.com/it-answers?id=33562864&s=Template:Maharashtra-school-stub&ttl=x%3AType+missing+in+UWP+-+How+override+base+control+style%3F

Comment: По поводу FindResource, можно попробовать как тут: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18670481

Comment: По поводу Register, посмотрите, как в UWP определяются DependencyProperty

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо большое за столько статеек) Все завтра изучу, а то уже поздно, мозги не варят)

Comment: @Denisok: для Register попробуйте указать 4-м параметром new PropertyMetadata(null)

Answer (score 2):

Напишу тут, чтобы по ссылкам не нужно было ходить. Замена x:Type

```
<Style x:Key="BasicButtonStyle" TargetType="ToggleButton">
... (This may contain nothing)
</Style>

<Style TargetType="RadioButton" 
   BasedOn="{StaticResource BasicButtonStyle}">
...
</Style>
```